use uv to install pytorch with cudnn support on win10
I want to install pytorch with uv on win 10.
First I tested it with pip and it worked. I used:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

Than, I removed pipo and the virtual env and inited uv.
uv add torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

Did not work.
uv pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

Installs something, but removes it on syncing.
I use uv in version "not sure": Installation states its 0.5.0 and uv version states it 0.4.22.
[[tool.uv.index]]
Is not recorgnised I currently use: 
[tool.uv.sources]
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124" }
torchvision = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124" }
torchaudio = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124" }

But this stops syncing as the url is no whl.
Somehow I got pytorch with cudnn working, after the 20th +x try, but still uv sync does not work anymore.

You can check the latest docs which has a special section for working uv with Pytorch

I check all installations with which. Had there installed. One in an python dir, one in an rust build dir and winget. I could find the first two with which uv than deleted these two installations. Reinstalled with winget. Then uv -V really did have version 0.5 Moreover uv behaved like in the documentation , as such that tool.uv.index was working.
